# Display whole alphabet in TableView Index List (landscape Orientation)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView` on a **Landscape ONLY** scene.

When implementing a Alphabetical Index List, not all letters are displayed.

Is there anyway I can force the Index List to show all 26 letters of Alphabet, or can we decrease IndexList font size or adjustFontToFit to make ALL LETTERS be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that `UITableView` automatically hides some of the indexes and replace them with a dot if they can't fit your table's height. I don't think there is any way you can change that, unless if you make your table taller.

(Anyway, if it makes you feel better, all the 26 letters can fit an iPhone 6 screen when in landscape and fullscreen.)

---

(Duplicate of [Indexed list for table view shows dot iOS 5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121929/indexed-list-for-table-view-shows-dot-ios-5)?)